# C# Stream Reader convert reader to Json

Tags: c#, .net

I don't know the correct syntax for this. I tried going by Intellisense and samples I found but I don't think I'm searching the right topic. I want to convert the response into an object. I think I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var code = response.StatusCode;

    if (code.ToString() == "OK")
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader, Organization);
        success = true;
    }
}
```

I just need it to read the response into a object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to deserialize using the stream instead of converting it to a string first:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResposeStream()))
using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
{
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize<Organization>(jsonTextReader);
}
```